# 'Cannot find module' with Angular2 lazy loading

Tags: angular, lazy-loading, angular2-routing, angular2-modules

Having trouble with implementing routing in combination with lazy loading.
My code can be found here: https://github.com/ahartvign/NetCoreDemos

Whenever I try to navigate to my lazy loaded route 'tracking', I get the error:
*Cannot find module './trackers/trackers.module'*

I've tried multiple different values for loadChildren:

```
'trackers/trackers.module#TrackersModule'  
'./trackers/trackers.module#TrackersModule'  
'/trackers/trackers.module#TrackersModule'
```

And all of the above with default export instead of *#TrackersModule*.

I've also tried restarting my server, as apparently some people have had problems with that.

Comment: I suspect you need to use one of special loaders like `ngtools/webpack`(thanks to the CLI-Team) or `angular-router-loader` (thanks to Brandon Roberts)

Comment: @yurzui I installed the angular-router-loader and managed to get it to work. I'm slightly confused as to why I needed to do that though. I thought this functionality was native? I've followed several guides online, and noone has mentioned this. Thanks regardless.

Answer (score 0):

Update : Add to your **app.routing.ts**

```
export const routing: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forRoot(routes,
        {enableTracing :true , preloadingStrategy :PreloadAllModules }
 );
```

Comment: Preloading is pretty cool, but it does nothing to solve the original problem. The router can't find the module.

Comment: are you available in teamviewer